# How to get all the columns in python where there's at least one pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType?

Tags: python, date, nat

I have a dataframe that looks like:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaT | 4 |
| 5 | 2020-10-14 19:37:15 | 5 |

I need to identify all the columns that have at least one `NaT` (`pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType`) in it. In this case it would be a result of:

```
[Column2]
```

What is a way to get such a list?

**Update:**

I think I have it now:

```
[i for i in df.columns if pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType in [type(item) for item in df[i]]]
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You could use isna() to check for missing and also examine the column data types.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, None, 4],
    [5,'2020-10-14 19:37:15',5]
], columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3'])

df['Column2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column2'])

# check for missing and also column data types
results = (df.isna().any()) & (df.dtypes=='datetime64[ns]')

# returns a Pandas Series:
results
Column1    False
Column2     True
Column3    False

# to output a list
results.index[results==True].to_list()
['Column2']
```